# it shows OS error if i try to open the links

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

i am making a webpage which looks like this using django  :

[the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Y9mo.png)

while opening the links , it shows OS error :
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\django projects\env\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\home\ran_num_gen.html'

i am unable to find out the cause of it. help me understand more about it . following is the relevant code and screenshots :

[DIRECTORIES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5A7t.png)

**views.py** :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template.context import Context
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    
    return render(request , 'home\home.html' )

def num_guess_game(request):

    return render (request ,'home\num_guess_game.html')

def ran_num_gen(request):

    return render (request ,'home\ran_num_gen.html')

def ran_pwd_gen(request):

    return render (request ,'home\ran_pwd_gen.html')
```

**urls.py** :

```
"""
URL configuration for core project.

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home.views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home ,name='home'),
    path('ran_num_gen/', ran_num_gen , name='ran_num_gen' ),
    path('ran_pwd_gen/', ran_pwd_gen ,name='ran_pwd_gen' ),
    path('num_guess_game/', num_guess_game , name='num_guess_game' ),

    
]
```

**home.html** :

```
{% extends 'home\base.html' %}

{% block title %}Welcome to homepage{% endblock title %}

 {% block content %}
 
 <h1>welcome to ALL ABOUT RANDOM</h1> 
 <p>i made this site to learn more about django</p>
 you can do the following things here :
  <hr>
 <li><a href="ran_num_gen/">Random number generator</a></li>
 <hr>
 <li><a href="ran_pwd_gen/">Random password generator</a></li>
 <hr>
 <li><a href="num_guess/">Random guess game</a></li>
 <hr>
 
 {% endblock content %}
```

i tried changing the name of links and adding the html extensions but it simply did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use forward slashes rather than escape characters:

e.g.,

```
'home\ran_num_gen.html'
```

...becomes...

```
'home/ran_num_gen.html'
```

...or...

```
r'home\ran_num_gen.html'
```

Comment: thanks, i used "r" and it started working .